# precision_recall_curve curve is returning only single value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision

With this classification problem, I am using Random Forest model. I was expecting it to return set of values for plotting precision and recall curve but it's not working.

[image]

I was following the tutorial that's given on this blogpost: https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-classification-in-python/

Update:

```
y_pred
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

```
y_test
array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Could you share your `y_test` and `y_pred`

Comment: instead of using `predict` you should use `predict_proba`.

Answer (score 1):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html

You are having multiple output in different arrays [lr_precision,lr_recall and _]

Edit : Just saw your predictions, they should be probability estimates